# Displaying blog categories in partial view on layout page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently I have a partial view where I manually display all my blog categories with links. I would like to make it dynamic by pulling from the database. I am not sure how to accomplish this within a partial view. I would even be willing to do it within the actual _layout page if it's easier that way.

Here is what I have right now.

_Categories.cshtml

```
<h2>Categories</h2>
<hr/>
<p>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Category", "Blog", new {id = 1})">ASP.Net MVC</a><br/>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Category", "Blog", new {id = 2})">Ruby on Rails</a><br/>
</p>
```

I would like to create these links dynamically as opposed to hard coding.

_Layout.cshtml

```
@Html.Partial("_Categories")
```

The main problem is there is no controller for the layout of a partial which is why I can't figure out how to go about it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a controller action named `ListCategories` in `BlogController` (or in a new   `CategoryController`). Add all the categories to the `ViewBag` in the action by querying them from your back-end database

```
public ActionResult ListCategories()
{
    ViewBag.Categories = db.Categories;
}
```

And use a `@foreach` loop in the view for the action `ListCategories.cshtml`:

```
<h2>Categories</h2>
<hr/>
<p>
    @foreach(Category c in ViewBag.Categories)
    {
        <a href="@Url.Action("Category", "Blog", new { id = c.Id })">@c.Name</a><br/>
    }
</p>
```

Finally, change your `_Layout.cshtml` to point to this action:

```
@Html.Action("ListCategories") 
// or @Html.Action("ListCategories", "CategoryController")
```